# Use php array stored in Memcached in node.js

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, node.js, memcached

In my web application, I save some information in a array, and save the array in Memcached.

Now I need to use this array in my node.js long polling server. Using [memcached](https://www.npmjs.org/package/memcached) module for node.js , when I try to get the array, as expected, its unreadable.

I have tried serializing the array before saving it in Memcached. It correctly shows the string in PHP, but it still shows the binary data when I try to get it from telnet and node.js .

Using the following to store the array :

```
$MC->set($identifier.':user:info',json_encode($from_db),1296000);
```

var_dump of `$from_db` :

```
string(417) "{"id":"1",
"username":"XXX",
"password":"XXX",
"email":"XXX",
"joined":"2014-05-06 22:52:12",
"ip":"XXX",
"rank":"XXX",
"reputation":"XXX",
"profile_update_visibility":"0",
"friends_visibility":"0",
"discussions_visibility":"0",
"private_discussions_visibility":"3",
"message_permission":"0",
 "hashed_username":"XXX"}"
```

`echo $MC->get("1:user:info");` shows the correct JSON :

```
{"id":"1","username":"XXX","password":"XXX","email":"XXX","joined":"2014-05-06 22:52:12","ip":"XXX","rank":"XXX","reputation":"XXX","profile_update_visibility":"0","friends_visibility":"0","discussions_visibility":"0","private_discussions_visibility":"3","message_permission":"0","hashed_username":"XXX"}
```

However, telnet and node.js show :

```
|l���sqD�R���l��S/�3XKX�����*�z�B�J�ڊ'��
���hf]��1�w�IJY�P)M��T=�Jk����TgdJъ����n���u%�/S&�٭���x�{3����I�^�^��y�lJH'/
,��cj����\���J��bĉOa��鑞1�?>�J��LM'�jRm�5�1�kE�jS|~��l                       �]���,�]��cǝݖ������px�;
```

Is the internal serialization of array in PHP by Memcached playing a role here? What are my options?

Comment: Store the array as string in JSON format using `json_encode()`.

Comment: @GergoErdosi tried that. PHP shows the JSON correctly, but telnet and node.js still show binary data.

Comment: Can you show us your code, so we can have more info about what you're doing? Also, showing PHP array and the results you're getting will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your string is stored compressed.

The Memcached library stores the item compressed when it's longer then some threshold.

You can use `Memcached::OPT_COMPRESSION = FALSE;` to disable the compression.

In your Node.js code you can convert the value to an object by using JSON.parse:

```
memcached.gets('1:user:info', function (err, data) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(data["1:user:info"]));
});
```

With your test example the result in Node.js will be:

```
{ id: '1',
  username: 'XXX',
  password: 'XXX',
  email: 'XXX',
  joined: '2014-05-06 22:52:12',
  ip: 'XXX',
  rank: 'XXX',
  reputation: 'XXX',
  profile_update_visibility: '0',
  friends_visibility: '0',
  discussions_visibility: '0',
  private_discussions_visibility: '3',
  message_permission: '0',
  hashed_username: 'XXX' }
```

Comment: The flag argument however is not present in the set method of `Memcached` http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.set.php , and currently I'm using `Memcached` object, not Memcache. I think setting the Memcached option Memcached::OPT_COMPRESSION to off will have the same effect?

Comment: Yep, setting Memcached::OPT_COMPRESSION to FALSE did it. Thanks! And make sure you edit your answer!

Comment: @abhishek sorry I for the misunderstanding. Fixed my answer to match your question :)